# Intercepting HTTP request in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I want to intercept all my `ajax` calls and change POST requests before they are sent.

I can intercept all `ajax` calls like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function() {
        alert('sending...');
    }
});
```

Now, how can I get the POST request and change it?

Comment: "change post request after sending" You mean before sending?!

Comment: yes yes :)... Fast typing :)

Comment: Just as an FYI, using ajaxSetup is strongly discouraged in the documentation, since it also affects the behavior of plugins: `The settings specified here will affect all calls to $.ajax or Ajax-based derivatives such as $.get(). This can cause undesirable behavior since other callers (for example, plugins) may be expecting the normal default settings. For that reason we strongly recommend against using this API.`

Comment: Because I'm using DJANGO i just want to attach csrf token to any request...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
        if(settings.type === "POST")
              settings.type = "GET";
    }
});
```